# Firebase auto-reconnect on android

Tags: java, android, firebase

Here is my code:

```
    firebaseRef.getRoot().child(".info/connected").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class)) {
                // We're connected (or reconnected)! Set up our presence state.
                firebaseRef.child("child").setValue("value");

            }
        }

        @Override public void onCancelled() { }
    });
```

Security rule of the "child" path:

```
".write": (auth != null);
```

When clients disconnect then reconnect `setValue("value");` is supposed to work.

It works perfectly on JS SDK.

However, Java SDK seems to have problem with reconnnect. It cannot `setValue("value")` there and Firebase returns `Permission denied` error.

Is something wrong there? Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was in fact a bug in the Firebase SDK. It was fixed in version 1.0.10, which can be downloaded here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/downloads.html

Comment: It works, thank you! The team is very responsive and helpful in patching this fix.