# Android Firebase setValue() Permission Denied

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-security, firebasesimplelogin

This is how the rules are defined on firebase:

```
{
"rules": {
 "users": {
  ".read": true,
    "$user_id": {
     ".write": "auth.uid === $user_id",
     ".read" : true
  }}}}
```

I have succesfully written new user information in my register activity using setValue() just like below, and also added new comments using push().setValue(), each time I didn't have an issue with authentication. New user written straight to http://DB/users/ while comments were added very deep.

Here is a code snippit, my code hits the Log: Data could not be saved. Everytime.

```
AuthData authData = newRef.getAuth();

    if (authData != null) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Auth as " + authData.getUid());
        Map<String, Object> newEntry = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        newEntry.put("Name", name);
        newEntry.put("Description", desc);
        newEntry.put("DueDate", date);
        newEntry.put("Status", 0);

        newRef.setValue(newEntry, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
                if (firebaseError != null) {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Data could not be saved. " + firebaseError.getMessage()); //Hits here every time.
                } else {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Data saved successfully. Finishing activity...");
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
        ;
    }
    else{
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "No authdata");
    }
```

Hopefully I've provided enough information, I'm guessing the issue is in the security/rules but any direction/guidance would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What version of Firebase are you using. Here is a post that describes a "Permission Denied" error being thrown when the `setValue()` method was called under certain conditions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817709/firebase-auto-reconnect-on-android. According to the accepted answer this was fixed as of version 1.0.10

Comment: I have the following in my dependencies: compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.2.3+'

Comment: Just want to add, I tried updateChildren() instead of setValue() just as an alternative and it returns the same Permission Denied.

Comment: Ughgh, sorry to anyone who wasted their time, my URL path was incorrect. I feel like a complete idiot.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know about the fix @thurst0n. I'll vote to close, based on it being a typo.

Comment: Fair enough! I was starring at that path forever but I wasn't checking the beginning just the end. heh.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I was too stuck on this point and here's what helped me.

First things first, there are two types of users who can access database from firebase

1. Authorized
2. Non-authorized

By default it is set to non-authorized but then they do not have any permissions neither **read** nor **write**, so initially if you try to perform any operation you get the *permission denied error*.

How to change this to suit your requirement?

**Solution:**

Under Database section, go to Rules tab. The URL will be something like this with your project name.
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/project-name/database/rules

You will see somthing like this here:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null", //non-authorised users CANT read
    ".write": "auth != null" //non-authorised users CANT write
  }
}
```

Just change this to

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null", //even non-authorised users CAN read
    ".write": "auth == null" //even non-authorised users CAN write
  }
}
```

Change this as per your requirement. Happy coding :)

Comment: When I opened database rules I found 
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
    
}
  
}

but if I am adding your mentioned code...fire base is not recognizing... any help

Answer (score 1):

I had the wrong path in my DB Reference.

http://DB-PATH/simplelogin:00/PERMISSION-DENIED

http://DB-PATH/users/simplelogin:00/Can-only-add-here

Answer (score 1):

For people who have this problem, do not forget to change the "type of database" that by default gives us firebase, it should be noted that there is 2 type of database one that is **Cloud Firestore** and another that is **RealTime Database**

To answer the question, make sure you are using **Realtime database:**

[image: Change the type of database]

Then edit the rules:

[image: Edit your security rules in the section of Database>Rules]

Obviously this configuration of rules should only be used for development environments, do not forget to change the rules when it is in production.