# Firebase : Permission denied - while setValue()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security

I am trying to build a chat application using firebase.

The structure for message table :

```
message -
   $message_id 
    - $message_push_id 
      - message {
        sender : 3, 
        receiver : 58,
        token : token_of_sender,
        message : hi 
        ....}
```

message_id here is generated using the sender and receiver ids  **"3_58"**

I am using push to save messages into firebase.

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
         "message":
        {
          "$messageid": {
            "$messagepushid":
            {
              ".read": true,
              ".write": "auth != null  && !data.exists()",
              ".indexOn": ["token", "userid", "receiverid", "sent_time"],
              ".validate": "auth.token == newData.child('token').val() && newData.hasChildren(['token', 'userid', 'receiverid', 'text'])"
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

I have already generated token using custom token generator :

```
Firebase firebase = getFirebase();
Map<String, Object> authPayload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
authPayload.put("uid", user.getUserid());
authPayload.put("token", user.getToken());
TokenGenerator tokenGenerator = new TokenGenerator(Constants.FIREBASE_KEY);
TokenOptions tokenOptions = new TokenOptions();
tokenOptions.setAdmin(false);
final String firebaseToken = tokenGenerator.createToken(authPayload, tokenOptions);
firebase.authWithCustomToken(firebaseToken, new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
        Log.d("Auth", "Success : " + authData.toString());
        Log.d("Auth", "Token : " + firebaseToken);
        SharedPrefs.setFirebaseUserToken(getActivity(), firebaseToken);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError
    firebaseError) {
        firebaseError.toException().printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

I am trying to push a new message but I am getting error :

**RepoOperation﹕ setValue at /message/3_58/-Jy2We4cqLjuQNF6Oyhs failed: FirebaseError: Permission denied**

I am unable to figure out where I am going wrong.

This is the code to send chat :

```
mConversationReferenceFireBase = mFireBase.child("message").child(mConversationId);
    Chat conversation = new Chat( mToken, mUserId, mReceiverId, message );
    mConversationReferenceFireBase.push().setValue(conversation, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
            if (firebaseError != null) {
                Log.e("Conversation", firebaseError.toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

mConversationId = 3_58

The token here is generated for a user. We have a separate server to maintain the user accounts. The token is being used to upload/ download any files, the firebase is used as Chat Server.

With the rules set to .read = true and .write = true; everything works, however when I am attempting to have an authentication performed, it results in the error mentioned above. I've tried using the token from token generator, to check if I may possibly be using the wrong token.

I am following this example to generate token for firebase auth :

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html

Since storing a firebase secret key is bad in terms of security, what other alternative can be followed to generate a token for authentication?

Comment: Did you validate that your application is allowed to set data on your server?

Comment: Yes, I am using the security secret key generated in firebase, I have tried without auth process, having .read: true and .write: true, the application works very well. I need a reference to the message id, so that I can update/ delete it, that's where 2 ids come in, one for message identification and other for push.

Comment: If you're generating tokens in the app that you're sending to your users, this means that you're embedding the secret of your Firebase into your APK. Someone will extract your APK, grab your key and be able to wreak havoc on your Firebase data. Please keep yourself safe from this scenario and *don't generate tokens in app that you ship to your users*.

Comment: Aside from that: it is difficult to be certain what is going wrong, without seeing the minimal code that triggers the error message. Please **edit** your question to include the code that performs `push().setValue()`. In addition: if you go to the Simulator tab of your dashboard, you can run the same write action there and get better feedback of why the write is being disallowed.

Comment: Thank you for pointing in the right direction @FrankvanPuffelen, we've modified the solution now.

Answer (score 3):

I was too stuck on this point and here's what helped me.

First things first, there are two types of users who can access database from firebase

1. Authorized
2. Non-authorized

By default it is set to non-authorized but then they do not have any permissions neither read nor write, so initially if you try to perform any operation you get the permission denied error.

So basically one has to change the required permissions on the firebase console in-order to access the database.

Complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37963998/3036759)

Answer (score 3):

Check the rule defined in your firebase account and also the simulator options. Description is given below in a image.

[image]